# How can I add a countdown for my chess game?

Tags: java, class, javafx, timer, countdown

I have been working on a chess game in **JavaFX**, which I think works good, but now I am trying to add like a countdown for both players. I tried to read documentations/watch youtube videos/search on StackOverflow and I finally managed to do it, I can print on the console the timer every second. 
The problem is that I have the code in another class and I want instead of printing on the console, to appear on my **GUI Application** (using the Text variable), so I don't know how can I send the countdown to my main class (I have used a `run()` method so I think that's impossible) and then add it to my panes, scene, etc. Or maybe there might be a way to add it to the scene or panes directly, I don't know.
This is my code for that countdown:

```
package com.mycompany.chess;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import org.w3c.dom.css.Counter;


public class MyThread extends Thread {
    static int min = 10;
    static int sec = 0;
    Text counter = new Text();


    public void run(){
       while(min>-1){
           if(sec == 0){
                min--;
                sec = 59;
            }
            if(sec<10){
                String seconds = String.valueOf(sec);
                String minutes = String.valueOf(min);
                counter.setText(minutes + ":0" + seconds);
                System.out.println(minutes + ":0" + seconds);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Counter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                sec--;
            }else{
                String seconds = String.valueOf(sec);
                String minutes = String.valueOf(min);
                counter.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
                System.out.println(minutes + ":" + seconds);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Counter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                sec--;
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

Please don't judge me if the code is messy or something like that, I am a complete begginer.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

From [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) tutorial by Oracle:

> The JavaFX scene graph, which represents the graphical user interface
>   of a JavaFX application is not thread-safe and can only be accessed
>   and modified from the UI thread also known as the JavaFX Application
>   thread.

According to it, you should not modify `JavaFX` components from a thread other than JavaFX Application Thread. 
Instead use JavaFX tools for it, as explained in the linked tutorial, and demonstrated in many easy to find examples such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53588490/3992939).